# hasMany mapping table not created

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am having a GORM issue.

I try to map one domain Object with another with `hasMany`.

```
class PrototypePriceModifierCode {
    ...
    static hasMany = [activitys:Activity]
    ...
}
```

Since I don't need a back reference in Class `Activity` I don't have any reference to `PrototypePriceModifierCode`.

Having only this creates my mapping table as expected (1).

```
prototype_price_Modifier_code_id activity_id
```

In the `Activity`, I need a reference to a `PrototypePriceModifier`, which has nothing to do with the above mapping table.

The problem is that the mapping table is not generated anymore as soon as I define

```
class Activity{
...
    PrototypePriceModifierCode prototypePriceModifierCodeAttached
```

How can I get the mapping table created *and* having a reference to `PrototypePriceModifierCode` in my Activity domain class?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
class Activity {

    static belongsTo = [PrototypePriceModifierCode]
}
```

This way, there will be a column in the `activity` table for `PrototypePriceModifierCode` instead of creating a separate table for `hasMany`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is that I need both:

1) The mapping table for N:M mapping between Activity and PrototypePriceModifierCode and
2) one reference to a one specific PrototypePriceModifierCode in class Activity

Comment: No unfortunately not! I don't have the mapping table.

Comment: May I'm not clear with your question then. Can you please elaborate more

Comment: Let me try it that way. What I want to achieve in the databases is the following:

I need to have 3 database tables:
1) Activity
2) PrototypePriceModifierCode
3) Mapping between 1 and 2 (prototype_price_Modifier_code_id activity_id)

In addition I need to have a field activity.price_modifier_code_id.

Answer (score 0):

When `Activity` does not have the `prototypePriceModifierCodeAttached` property, the `hasMany` in `PrototypePriceModifierCode` results in a uni-directional one-to-many association. In the database, this is implemented with a mapping table.

However, when `Activity` has the `prototypePriceModifierCodeAttached` property the association changes to a bi-directional one-to-many. In the database this means the `activity` table has a foreign key pointing to it's `prototype_price_modifierCode`, so the mapping table is not used. You can read more about these differences [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/).

### "prototypePriceModifierCodeAttached" property

If you want a uni-directional one-to-many *and* the property `Activity.prototypePriceModifierCodeAttached`, you can create a getter method which looks up the `PrototypePriceModifierCode`:

```
class Activity {

    PrototypePriceModifierCode getPrototypePriceModifierCodeAttached() {
        PrototypePriceModifierCode.where {
            activitys.id == this.id
        }.get()
    }

}
```

The downside here is that the property is inaccessible to GORM; can't query on it.

### "price_modifier_code_id" column

On the other hand, if what you want is a `price_modifier_code_id` column in the `activity` table, you can add it as a `long`:

```
class Activity {

    long prototypePriceModifierCodeAttached

    static mapping = {
        prototypePriceModifierCodeAttached column: 'price_modifier_code_id'
    }
}
```

This makes it possible to use GORM queries on the property, but only on the `PrototypePriceModifiedCode` ID, not the domain class instance itself.

### A combo

You can combine both approaches, as long as you're willing to do a bit of maintenance:

```
class Activity {

    long priceModifierCodeId // <--- You gotta maintain this property manually.

    PrototypePriceModifierCode getPrototypePriceModifierCodeAttached() {
        PrototypePriceModifierCode.get(priceModifierCodeId)
    }
}
```

Note: *activitys* is misspelled. It should be *activities*.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using String saving comma separated ids.

```
String activitys

this.activitys.split(',')each{
        p.activitys.add(Activity.get(Long.parseLong(it)))
}
```

As I don't need referencial integrity here this works fine for me.